# Next JS can not access to the localStorage

Tags: authentication, next.js, jwt, local-storage, server-side-rendering

I building an application with next JS.

When authenticating the user via login page I can store the access token and refresh token to the local storage normally. But during authorization, when I am trying to get the access token from local storage I am getting an error called localstorage is not defined.

I guess because next JS is rendering the page on the server side, and there is not localstorage on the server.

So, how can I get around this? Any help would be appriciated.

```js
// Set access token and refresh token to localstorage
const setTokens = (accessToken, refreshToken) => {
  localStorage.setItem("accessToken", accessToken);
  localStorage.setItem("refreshToken", refreshToken);
};

// Get access token from localstorage
const getAccessToken = () => {
  return localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
};

// Get refresh token from localstorage
const getRefreshToken = () => {
  return localStorage.getItem("refreshToken");
};

// Remove access token and refresh token from localstorage
const removeTokens = () => {
  localStorage.removeItem("accessToken");
  localStorage.removeItem("refreshToken");
};

export { setTokens, getAccessToken, getRefreshToken, removeTokens };
```

From above code only setToken() function is working.

Comment: The code is fine as long as you call these functions inside a `useEffect`, where `localStorage` is always available.

Answer (score 1):

use your function in `useEffect`

```
const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState(null)
const [refreshToken, setRefreshToken] = useState(null)
useEffect(() => {
  try {
    const accToken = getAccessToken();
    const refToken = getRefreshToken();
    setAccessToken(accToken)
    setRefreshToken(refToken)
  } catch (e) {
  }
}, [])
```